# CSS only targetting first line in a comment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

So I have comments in my app and the issue is once the content in the comment becomes three lines it wraps below the users picture instead of starting where the other lines do. I'm pretty new to CSS but it seems whatever margins I apply it only moves the first line.

[image]

CSS:

```
#comment_border {
  border: 1px solid $grayLighter;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #d6e5f1;
  margin-left: 90px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.comment_info {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: #767676;
}

#comment_content {
  /* dont know what to put here */
}
```

View/comments:

```
<div class="row" id="comment_border">

<span class="comment_info">
  <aside class="span2">
    <%= link_to gravatar_for((comment.user), size: 35), comment.user %>
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user, id: "feedusername" %>
  </aside>
  <span id="comment_content"> <%= comment.content %> </span>
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: could you pop this into a js fiddle? think its a case of your html layout, but a fiddle would enable easier diagnosis

Comment: fiddle came out different: http://jsfiddle.net/R9YuV/.

Comment: The fiddle is different because it has different code, lacking much of the original.

Comment: it isnt pulling in bootstrap css either but add this to css @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R9YuV/1/ still a bit different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem description is incomplete (essential CSS missing etc.), but the main problem seems to be that you are setting left margin on an inline element. With the given markup, the following CSS modifications render it in a way that seems to be roughly what is meant:

```
.comment_info {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #767676;
  /* margin-left:-20px; NOT set here */
}
#comment_content {
  margin-left: 90px;
  display: block;
}
.span2 { 
  width: 80px; 
  height: 35px; 
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px red;
 }
```

It would be more logical to use a `div` element and not `span` for the comment content; doing so, you could drop the `display: block` declaration.

P.S. You shouldn’t really use `aside` here; it’s not meant for purposes like this, and it just confuses some old browsers; use `div` instead.